# Elements of container removing itselves?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I have a class:

```
class C1 {
    std::vector<C2> vec;
};
```

I'd like to implement C1 and C2 class that element in vector (of C2 class) can cause removing itself from container vec. How to do this best?

Maybe I can pass reference to C1 class to C2 class and call method in C1 to remove this element. Is it nice solution? How to do that in C++11?

(C1 is the only one class in the program)

Comment: Have you tried to write code for the solution you suggest?

Comment: In order to decouple `C2` from how it's stored, you could give it a function to call that knows how to perform the action.

Comment: You have to maintain ownership, otherwise you end up in circular references (resource/memory leaks)

Comment: Rather than having your C2 object try to remove itself (which is likely to get messy), how about having a boolean "dead" variable in your C2 object.  When your C2 object wants to go away, it sets the "dead" variable to true, and the other code that looks in the vector knows not to do anything with C2 objects whose "dead" flag is set (except maybe remove them from the vector -- something that can be done whenever is convenient).

Answer (score 2):

I think that intrusive containers are nice solution to your problem, so if you not necessarily have to use std::vector, then I would suggest to take a look at them (intrusive containers are something close to container of pointers, where each element stores reference to next and previous element, which makes it easy for element to remove itself from container). boost have nice library of intrusive containers, so in case you use it, you won't have to write everything from scratch. Take a look here, to see what are differences between std::vector (non-intrusive container) and intrusive containers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html.

Answer (score 0):

As @JeremyFriesner suggests, one solution is to construct C2 objects with callback functions for removal - but you have to be careful not to destruct the object while its method code is running (well, you might be able to pull this off but it's somewhat dangerous). Maybe some tricks with holding onto a shared_ptr would help (or maybe not).

Also, instead of a callback function you could have C2's assume they're contained in vectors, or other similar containers, and just have them store a (plain? weak?) pointer to the vector.

Finally, and I hate to do this, but - are you absolutely sure you need to have C2s remove themselves from the vector? That is, are you sure the semantics of the classes requires it, and it can't be the (simpler) case of C1 removing them? The answer you provide yourself might also give you a direction for how to implement the removal mechanism.